# Create a symbolic link in a mapped drive in Windows 10 - access is denied

Tags: windows-10, vpn, permissions, remote-desktop, symbolic-link

After struggling for an entire day, I'm afraid I need to ask this question again because none of the solutions proposed in this forum seems to work.

**ISSUE**

I need to create a symbolic link to a folder in a mapped drive from a different directory on the same mapped drive. I always get "Access is denied".

Note 1: I can create local to local symbolic links.
Note 2: I can create local to remote symbolic links.
Note 3: I can NOT create remote to local symbolic links.
Note 4: I can NOT create remote to remote symbolic links.

**SETUP** - EDITED

I'm working on a laptop, connected via VPN to my employer's network, and RemoteDesktop to the workstation that I operate. All run in Windows 10.

- I have User rights on the laptop.
- I have permission to create symbolic links on the laptop.
- I have "fsutil behavior query SymlinkEvaluation" ALL enabled (L2L, L2R, R2L, R2R) on the laptop.
- I have Admin rights on the workstation.
- I have permission to create symbolic links on the workstation (redundant to having Admin rights).
- I have "fsutil behavior query SymlinkEvaluation" ALL enabled (L2L, L2R, R2L, R2R) on the workstation.
- I have permission on the mapped drive set to MAX.
- I have set the UAC to "never"
- The mapped drive is mapped in both the laptop (reminder: User rights) and the workstation (reminder: Admin rights)

**UPDATE**

I've tried to do the same from **inside** the network (not using the VPN) but the outcome is the same: "Access is denied".

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SuperUser. Can you please explain what you tried, and how.

Comment: So on which computer is this happening?

Comment: This is happening on the workstation. The only thing I use the laptop for is accessing the workstation - but now I'm wondering if the laptop's setup is playing a role here.

Comment: @MosheGross after setting everythin as explained above, I try creating the symbolic links via CMD typing "mklink /D <link> <target>". As I point out, the method does work for local, not for remote drives.